# Specific sites (i.e. YouTube and Reddit) are lagging on Chromium-based browsers

Tags: google-chrome, browser, youtube, microsoft-edge, brave

Specific websites, namely YouTube and Reddit are lagging for me. It's not slow internet speed, but rather lagging. When I hover over a video to pause it, my mouse takes about 2 seconds before it turns into a pointer cursor. When I press the space bar to pause a video, it takes 2 seconds before it pauses the video. When I type a comment, I have to wait 2 seconds before it activates the comment box, and when I type a comment it staggers my letters.

However: **Microsoft Edge has no problem on YouTube or Reddit. There is absolutely no lagging on Edge.** I only mention these two sites because these are the only two sites I use that have problems so far.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Uninstalled my extensions (EXCEPT 1 SEE ANSWER)
- Run virus checks from both malwarebytes and Mcaffee (nothing found)
- I have both Chrome Browser and Brave browser (both running on Chromium) that experience the lagging. I have tried switching accounts to no avail.

This only happened after my most recent Windows update which was like 2-3 days ago. There have been no changes to what I have been doing besides the windows update.

What could be the cause of this weird lag for specific sites only for Chromium-based Browsers?

Comment: Just so you know, Edge is also Chromium-based now.

Comment: Might be a GPU driver issue. Try updating the GPU driver to the latest version, and/or try toggling GPU hardware acceleration in the settings.

Comment: @pigeonburger ah, thanks did not know that, makes it even weirder...

Comment: @galacticninja Just tried, did not improve the situation. Also I get the same Lag on LMS canvas tools for my University. It hasn't gone away yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an extension causing my problems:

McAfee® WebAdvisor extension

As soon as I turned it off my YouTube and every other website stopped lagging. I am not sure why they would purposely throttle my browser performance as a result. I have had this extension for over a year and never encountered problems.

Comment: In your question, you mentioned that you've uninstalled all of your extensions. Did the McAfee extension remain installed?

Comment: @galacticninja yes it was, I coincidently uninstalled all of them except that one because I thought "there's no way", my mistake. I apologize.